# AWS Cognito Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

In my Javascript-based web application, I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.24.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId : 'XXXXX',
        secretAccessKey : 'XXXX'
    });
    AWS.config.region = 'AWS_REGION';
</script>
```

However this allows users to see all my keys. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Yes . I had the same problem
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html link really helps

Answer (score 0):

One option here is to have an API that you control generate a pre-signed URL for the JS client to upload to. This page should help - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html